# _Generic() macro not expanding

Tags: c, clang, c-preprocessor

So I'm trying to implement a "generic printing macro":

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>

#define CHECK(x) printf(#x " =" \
        _Generic((x), float: double: "%f",\
                  int: "%d",\
                  default: "Cannot print this with CHECK(x)")\
        , x)

int main(void){
    CHECK(FLT_RADIX);
    return 0;
}
```

This gives me error:

```
main.c:11:2: error: expected ')'
        CHECK(FLT_RADIX);
        ^
main.c:5:3: note: expanded from macro 'CHECK'
                _Generic((x), float: double: "%f",\
                ^
main.c:11:2: note: to match this '('
main.c:4:24: note: expanded from macro 'CHECK'
#define CHECK(x) printf(#x " =" \
                       ^
1 error generated.
```

After running `clang main.c -E`, the output is:

```
int main(void){
 printf("FLT_RADIX" " =" _Generic((2), float: double: "%f", int: "%d", default: "Cannot print this with CHECK(x)") , 2);
 return 0;
}
```

So how to make `_Generic()` expand during translation?

BTW: Which `)` didn't I match?

Comment: I don't think you can gang the `float:` and `double:` terms together like that — and that's a source of the error message.  Maybe you should use a static assertion in the `default:` clause so the code doesn't compile if the code won't work.

Comment: Another possible solution would be `#define CHECK(X) (printf("%s", #x " ="), printf(_Generic(.......` (rest the same as you had it, fixing the fallthrough as Jonathan Leffler notes below)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: There are actually two errors. The one you mention would arise later in the text (see the error-mark).

Comment: several very good examples (much too long to post here) can be found at: `http://www.robertgamble.net/2012/01/c11-generic-selections.html`

Comment: "I'm trying to implement a "generic printing macro":" --> This may help [Formatted print without the need to specify type matching specifiers using _Generic](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/115143/29485)

Comment: What does the `#x` do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`_Generic` is not a macro, but a [primary expression](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.1) (see also 6.5.1.1). As such it is evaluated at a later translation phase (7) than string concatenation (phase 6). See the standard, [5.1.1.2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.1.2). Briefly: When the compiler concatenates strings, the `_Generic` has not been evaluated, yet.

You have to pass the converted value as a string argument to `printf` or call a seperate `printf` with format-string for the value. One approach keeping the macro small would be to use a helper-functions you pass a type-code plus the actual value in a `union`. That function would then use a `switch` to do the conversion & printing. Or you use a different function for each type. Of course there are various alternatives.

Ok, here is **one** (not necessarily the best) approach:

```
#define CHECK(x) _Generic((x), double: print_as_double(#x, x), \
                  float: print_as_double(#x, x),
                  int: print_as_int(#x, x), \
                  default: printf("Cannot print this with CHECK(x)") )

void print_as_float(const char *name, double value)
{
    printf("%s = %lf", value);
}

...
```

Note you cannot combine different type-names in a *generic-association*, that's why I had to split the `float` and `double` entry.

Sidenote: The name `CHECK` is missleading, as the functions does not really check something at run-time. A better name would be e.g. "PRINT_VALUE".

Comment: Do you mean something like `printf("%s", "%d", 42);`? That doesn't work

Comment: @sunqingyao: This is not possible with `printf`. You cannot nest format strings. But you can write a small meta-`printf`.

Comment: @sunqingyao No, he means `printf("%d", 42);`